# How to archive data from Azure Data lake by validating the size of file in source and destination

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have different zones in Azure Data lake and i am trying to move data from one zone to another and then deleting data from the first zone. But before the delete the data i need to compare the size of source and destination file.

I have created a pipeline in ADF which copies data from one zone to another and delete data from first zone. But i dont know how to compare the size before deleting.

CopyData->Delete

Compare the size of source and destination files and then perform delete task

Answer (score 0):

Use the Get Metadata activity against your source and target, then compare in an If conditional

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This will work, the only confusion i have here is everytime i use getmetadata, it is not showing me siz as an option.

Comment: Look under Data Set field list of your Get Metadata activity

Comment: it gives you the size option when you are picking up a file and to validate. But if you want to check the content of files in that folder in data lake and compare it with the files in other folder, this wont work.